# Android service ending and reopening when activity ends

Tags: android, service

I have a service which I start on a new thread like that:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MessagingService.class);
            startService(in);
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

It maintains a TCP connection for push messaging. Everything works fine, until I swipe the app left in the recent apps menu so that it closes.

When the app closes the connection gets dropped and reconnects immediately. Reading the log:

```
06-04 20:57:01.735  15238-15238/com.test.app V/MessagingService﹕ onStartCommand()
06-04 20:57:02.065  15238-15238/com.test.app I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@425e4220 time:99066408
06-04 20:57:05.145  15238-15238/com.test.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-04 20:57:10.635  15795-15795/com.test.app D/ActivityThread﹕ handleBindApplication:com.test.app
06-04 20:57:10.635  15795-15795/com.test.app D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
06-04 20:57:10.635  15795-15795/com.test.app D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
06-04 20:57:10.685  15795-15795/com.test.app V/MessagingService﹕ onStartCommand()
```

Why does the `onStartCommand()` get called again when the app "closes" (it's not a force close). Is there any way to let it run smoothly?

Comment: See my answer to that question

Answer (score 0):

I think that You should use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to run Service in new thread.